# Combined right triangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to draw this one? I can only do the triangle AED.

Comment: You may find some good help in the *Related* menu on the right. This could be achieved in many different ways. One would be to use the `tkz-euclid` library that does almost all the calculations for you. Another way to do this is to use `intersections`, `angles` and `calc` libraries. First, think of how you would draw this by hand (in which order), then try and replicate it in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: [A useful link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614466/204164).

Comment: I am sure that there are many here who can help. It is not trivial to do, but you really need to try yourself and post a minimal working example along with a description of what is causing you problems. If you get stuck after AED, then post the code for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm drawing this with plain Ti*k*Z, but perhaps `tkz-euclide` is a better option as SebGlav says in the comments.

First use Ti*k*Z to compute all the distances and angles, then I set the `coordinate`s with the help of `calc` library and draw the triangles. Last I draw the angles, obviously with the `angles` library.

BTW, I'm assuming that the three angles in B are equal.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {siunitx} % for \ang
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,scale=2]
% distances and angles
\def\CD{1}   % CD distance
\def\CG{0.5} % CG distance
\def\DE{1}   % DE distance
\def\aC{35}  % angle C
\def\aE{53}  % angle E
\pgfmathsetmacro\AD{\DE*tan(\aE)}     % AD distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\AC{\AD+\CD}          % AC distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\AB{\AC*tan(\aC)}     % AB distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\BG{\AC/cos(\aC)-\CG} % BG distance
\pgfmathsetmacro\aB{90-\aC}           % angle B (assuming the three angles are equal)
\pgfmathsetmacro\BF{\BG*cos(\aB)}     % BF distance   
% coordinates
\coordinate (E) at (0,0);
\coordinate (D) at (\DE,0);
\coordinate (A) at (\DE,\AD);
\coordinate (C) at (\DE,-\CD);
\coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(\AB,0)$);
\coordinate (G) at ($(C)!\CG cm!(B)$);
\coordinate (F) at ($(B)+(2*\aB-180:\BF)$);
\coordinate (H) at ($2*(F)-(G)$);
% triangles
\draw (A) node [above] {$A$} -- (D) node [below left] {$D$} -- (E) node [below left] {$E$} -- cycle;
\draw (A) -- (B) node [above] {$B$} -- (C) node [below] {$C$}  -- cycle;
\draw (B) -- (F) node [below] {$F$} -- (G) node [below right] {$G$} -- cycle;
\draw (B) -- (F)  -- (H) node [right] {$H$} -- cycle;
% angles, with angles library
\draw[blue] pic [draw] {angle=D--E--A} node [above,xshift=0.8cm] at (E) {\ang{\aE}};
\draw[blue] pic [draw] {angle=B--C--A} node [right,yshift=1cm]   at (C) {\ang{\aC}};
\draw[red]  pic [draw] {angle=A--B--C};
\draw[red]  pic [draw,angle radius=0.7cm] {angle=C--B--F};
\draw[red]  pic [draw] {angle=F--B--H};
\draw[red]  pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {right angle=E--D--A};
\draw[red]  pic [draw,angle radius=3mm] {right angle=G--F--B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were really fast, I just typed the preamble on this one ;)

Comment: Thanks @SebGlav. This is the kind of problem that I draw the most with Ti*k*Z, so I'm used to them.